# Implementation of Android on Raspberry-Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

am working on a project where i run Raspberry Pi on Android(Gingerbread), what we are trying to do in this project is that we take readings(teperature and light) from a Zigbee(pikkerton) device,the Zigbee device sends the data to a dongle which is plugged in to raspberry pi, we should read the values on raspberry pi via dongle and display it on Android

1. we have successfully installed Android OS on Raspberry pi, connect the output from raspberry pi on to a monitor and control it via mouse and Keyboard.
2. we are developing the code in NDK(an App which reads the values from dongle and displays the same).
3. Need some inputs on methods from which we can establish serial communication between the zigbee dongle and raspberry pi via NDK

Comment: Hi Darshan! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is pretty open-ended and, as such, doesn't fit the format for questions on SO. If you have specific questions about your implementation, feel free to ask them. Your question will probably get closed because it feels a lot like "I have a homework project to do, can someone supply me with the code for it please?"

Comment: Actually, this question probably is both appropriate and answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice CanSpice,we had successfully implemented the same idea on Raspberry pi using Linux OS and Python code.so i have logic and the code, we are just trying out other possibilities.needed some guidance as i am very new to android programming.

Comment: @Darshan eventually how you solved your problem >

Comment: As Chris Stratton had suggested, i had to tweak the kernel so that the kernel provided permission to create /dev/ttyUSB0(the presence of this node in the /dev folder is the indication that your raspberry-pi has ability to detect the USB attached to it) when the dongle was attached.

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation ...this link is helpful to learn about kernel compilation..its not that hard...some 2-3 days of work....if ur good at linux ,it would just take a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your dongle provides a serial interface, so you have two broad types of choices:

**1. You can let a linux-level driver create a serial interface**

You will need to have whatever creates the serial device (/dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyACM0 or the like) set the permissions to allow all users access.  Or you can set the permissions to allow only access to a hard-coded unix-level user group id, and modify your Android installation to add a new android permission which results in membership of the app's userid in that unix group so that it can access the port.   (See how Internet and External Storage permissions are handled for an example of doing this in a way any app can utilize, or how the radio device is handled for a restricted example)   You then use normal linux serial APIs to access the port from your NDK code, or Java serial APIs to do so from Java code.

**2. You can disable any linux-level driver, and talk to the raw USB device from Android application code**

First check if the release of Android you are using has the USB host APIs; if not you will need to upgrade it first.   This method will require less customization of Android, but may require more understanding of the actual USB communication with the dongle.  However you will likely be able to track down example code for talking to similar devices from an Android app.

Comment: Thanks for helping Chris, I think Gingerbread supports USB host API, because i can connect mouse and keyboard to my Raspberry-PI and the OS responds to click of the mouse button and keyboard..i will try to implement the second method you suggested.

Comment: On a device without it's own touchscreen, I wouldn't assume that  support of a USB mouse & keyboard means that the Android USB Host APIs are present for use by apps.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html ...this link tells me that Android 2.3.4 can be used for USB Communication and supports USB Accessory though it does not support USB host directly.

Comment: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=262..... helpful for anyone whos working in similar projects to mine

Comment: Accessory mode won't help unless there is something else in your installation which can act as a USB *host*.

Comment: Would connecting a USB card reader to the work of USB host work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you rephrase?

Comment: I read this "In USB accessory mode, the external USB hardware act as the USB hosts. Examples of accessories might include robotics controllers; docking stations; diagnostic and musical equipment; kiosks; card readers; and much more. This gives Android-powered devices that do not have host capabilities the ability to interact with USB hardware"          source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html ..  i thought something like this would work..

Comment: If you have some external device which can be a host - unlike the device-only peripherals you are used to seeing on the market.  Such is likely to cost nearly as much as a pi, so leveraging the pi's host capability would probably be desirable - either with a later Android version, or by using the linux-level method underneath Android.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you have been a great help. Can you enlighten me regarding "using the linux-level method underneath Android" , some reference reads perhaps...how do i go about it?. I came across some websites which says libusb would do the work of serial USB communication, is that the direction?, im still testing out all possibilities....

Comment: As in my 1) above, the same way you would on any other linux (kernel driver or libusb or whatever works for this peripheral), only using one of the mentioned methods to solve the permission problem.